# Where does Outlook load its e-mail icons from?

Tags: outlook, icons, embedded-resource

Where does Outlook 2010 load these e-mail icons from?

[image: Outlook e-mail icons]

I found a lot of icons in outlook.exe and outllibr.dll, but some are not among them.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following workaround to extract the icons:

- Activate the Windows Classic theme
- Make a screenshot containing the desired icons
- Set the window background color to black
- Make another screenshot
- Use [this python script](http://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=Extracting_alpha) to reconstruct the alpha channel